# How to add film grain using the compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

How to add film grain using compositing nodes.

Comment: Do you want fake grain, or real grain captured from film?  Do you want one frame of grain, or do you want a grain overlay for video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. To add film grain using the compositor you first need to create a noise texture.
2. Go to the texture propertiers and click new, then select noise.
3. After that, go to the compositor.
4. Add a Texture node and select your noise texture.
5. Add a Mix node and set it's type to Screen. Turn Clamp on.
6. Plug your render to the top image slot and the noise texture to the bottom one.
7. Adjust the Fac to your liking.
8. You are good to go!

[image]

Comment: (I forgot to check the Mix Node's Clamp on the image)

Comment: Just a heads up to people that a.t.m. this does not work with the real time compositor being in alpha (in my case blender 3.4 alpha).