# How to create an animated gradient backdrop with noise-like effect

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, animation-nodes, glass

Im trying to create an animated backdrop that creates a similar effect to the noise-like textures often used in Illustrator or Adobe after effects. Is there a simple and easy way to achieve that in blender;

My current methodology is to create a frost glass vertical plane at the front (to soften the effect - and add grain-like effect) and place a voronoi texture behind that which is going to be animated; illuminating onto the front glass;

I will link a video to show what Im going for approximately
https://streamable.com/xj0vz7

[image]

What Im doing kind of works, but Im interested to find out whether this is overkill and theres other better ways to go about it;

PS. Yes, I just started Blender a few days ago, complete noob.

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get something close to what you show with a *Noise Texture* plugged into a *ColorRamp*. Also mix a *Musgrave* with the *Texture Coordinate* into a *MixRGB* in order to twist the spots a bit. Then animate the *Mapping* on the Z location (or, as Allen Simpson says, switch the *Noise Texture* to 4D and keyframe the W value). If you want some grains, do it in the *Compositor*, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238692/how-to-add-film-grain-using-the-compositor):

[image]

[image]

You could also make it more complicated and mix several of these effects with a n&b musgrave as factor...

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: Noise texture also has a 4d option which gives you a W value for changing the noise over time instead of moving it through space. :)

Comment: @Allen Simpson oh you're right I always forget the W value, I'm going to edit