# How Could I Generate Camera Noise?

Tags: compositing-nodes

How could I create a realistic camera noise look?

Examples:
[image: camera noise]

Comment: there was a similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238692/how-to-add-film-grain-using-the-compositor but maybe the best is to find a grainy movie that you'll put over your film, like https://www.holygrain.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Noise texture?

[image: img1]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html