# Are there any ways to make texture overlay (moving texture) repeat animation and noise on the model?

Tags: animation, texturing, compositing-nodes, animation-nodes

Does everyone know the answer?

I love making different art styles in a blender.   I'd like to try to have the model character's moving texture like "Norman Rockwell's Doctor and Doll" from https://www.artstation.com/artwork/xJe3yX *(Animated by Jorge Bompart)* ----please check for animated only.

[image]

Can you Please demonstrate and make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it by myself.

texture for example:
[image]

Another gif for example.
[image]

Comment: What is the problem? You don't know how to overlay a texture, do you? You don't know how to use procedural noise, right? Do you know how to loop a procedural texture? Do you want to do it in viewport? You don't know how to distort an image, maybe? Last example made by morphing several images, btw, it is different aproach.

Comment: I'm a beginner. I really don't know much about blender.

Comment: does this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238692/how-to-add-film-grain-using-the-compositor